# Creating ISAPI filter in c++

Tags: c++, mfc, isapi

I want to create  ISAPI filter in c++ of following example,
Steps that I used is,
Create new win32 DLL and paste code that mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972826 but i dont known why my code not create ISAPI filter properly..

Please give me some suggestion I am very newbiee in ISAPI filter, How to create ISAPI filter properly for an example mentioned it in this post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972826 example

Comment: have you mentioned your functions name in .def file??

Comment: @Aryabhata yes i do i known if i doesnt then there is linking problem while getting function.

Comment: Did you set up IIS to enable ISAPI filters? Did you implement and export all required entry-points as outlined in the [IIS ISAPI Filters Development Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525908.aspx)? Also look into [Creating ISAPI Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525164.aspx) for additional information. It would also help if you provided minimal code and your .def file.